# How did Jack Wilder appear in two places at the same time?

Tags: plot-explanation, now-you-see-me-2

In Now You See Me 2, before the final trick (I refer to the plane on the Thames, England), three of the four horseman (Jack, Daniel, Lula) are performing a street trick at their respective place.

Merritt McKinney is supposed to perform another street trick too, but is intercepted by his brother (Chase). Now I'm getting confused as to how Jack appeared at Merrit's place while he was supposed to be at another place at that time.

Comment: However, while I realise this is a huge plot hole for such a usually well-thought-out film, Jack never actually received a call from Dylan. He could have already finished his trick and headed to Merritt.

Answer (score -1):

Merrit was intercepted earlier in the day by his brother Chase, before the evening's street magic took place.  Jack was there to help him out as they had expected this to happen.  After which they went off to their separate locations for the evening's public tricks.

Comment: Sorry for the necro, but this answer doesn't make sense. Merrit being intercepted is the reason the other tricks get called off and end early. Chronologically, the tricks are happening, then merrit gets intercepted, he calls the leader, the leader calls the rest of them. We also know it happens in this order because the 'bad guys' find out the location of the final act AFTER they've been watching the other 3 perform and trying to find a pattern. If chase intercepted first before the performances started, they would have already known and not needed to look for the pattern. Just watched the mov

Answer (score -1):

Well if you watch the movie closely you would see that while they all were at the (Thames England) jack was explaining the whole trick in which he stated (the whole card trick was done by the use of escape doors and doubles) which also explains how he was in two places at once.

Comment: In which he stated what?